# I having an error in cmd saying when trying to open jupyter notebook traceback (recent call last)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Trying to open my jupyter. When I run command prompt I am getting an error saying Traceback recent call last. How can I solve this

I tried to restart my pc and started again but non worked

Comment: You should really include the whole error you get